# Null keys when using `debug_storageRangeAt`

Tags: storage, rpc, besu, hyperledger, debugging

I'm currently trying to use the `debug_storageRangeAt` on a Hyperledger Besu RPC to extract the contract storage. For some contracts I get the expected response which is a list of keys and values:

```json
"0x9d0103847e82e6as1b84ca8da0aa2d7cdd70d1c25e5d1b100813d3d5a52b08d6": {
    "key": "0x5c9a861a90d07f2f2320573b42657e37376714fbce7afae3500c833bc6d6c41d",
    "value": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000031"
},
"0xb10e2d527612073b26eecdfd717e6a320cf44b4afac2b0732d9fbde2b7fa0cf6": {
    "key": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
    "value": "0x000000000000000000000000a2497eec6f3c4c5c6a7a2e522f6042085659aeaf"
},
```

But some other contracts that I query return `null` values inside the key field, even though they hold a value.

```json
"0x0009a646fb76b2c15e0db60249e33e2ff2e75a2ab671feac02f9876a5c252941": {
    "key": null,
    "value": "0x0000000000000000000000003706765b1986788be6453d37b89cb76ee249d240"
},
"0x000cb2319144140bbed3890ef3de9cf54bfd5adb202d49b2eb5aeba5b716e208": {
    "key": null,
    "value": "0x000000000000000000000000962c9956a04f3377671ea309b936e5e7cf81d967"
},
"0x002160d994a7b7fdcdfd6bd72e520a8284ebfc15e494ed8689f5c6d205f1db06": {
    "key": "0xc22bc41c71fccd17556f21a8a560aaab7e80d32405436c96373b10ce8880ed24",
    "value": "0x00000000000000000000002367207a5353e78aa5859449172bgh8f653fee117a"
},
```

Why could this be happening and how could I possibly fix it either in my request or the config of the node.

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR: today in Besu, there are a couple cases where you will get a null key in the response for `debug_storageRangeAt`:

1. the storage hash key has been evicted from the in-memory pre-image cache
2. the storage entry was not modified recently, and therefore was never in the pre-image cache

The Ethereum yellow paper specifies that account storage keys are hashed, by spec.  Presumably it is specified this way to ensure the account trie is balanced and not too deep.  So what is saved in the account state trie is the hashed account storage slot key.

The `debug_storageRangeAt` method response consists of the pre-image storage slot key and value for each hashed storage slot key.

As of Besu 23.4.4 and prior, in order for Besu to get that pre-image storage slot key, it has to be in the cache.  That means the storage entry has to have been modified recently.  Besu's `debug_storageRangeAt` implementation replays the block up to the transaction specified, so any storage slot that would have been modified in that block should be present in the pre-image cache.

But of course, since it is a cache, it has a limited size, and only will have entries that have been recently modified.

So for case #1 above, if the node is executing other blocks or the block you are debugging has a lot of account storage modification, some of the pre-image keys might have been evicted.

But what you are more likely to encounter is case #2 where the storage entry hasn't been touched recently, so its hash pre-image just isn't in the cache.
If you want to fix case #1, we can configure the size of the pre-image cache to a larger value, perhaps expose this as a CLI param.

But since you are more likely to encounter case #2 for contracts that have existed for quite some time, that is a tougher nut to crack.
Besu could implement a feature, like geth, that when running in an archive mode (i.e. sync-mode=FULL) you can persist the pre-image cache to disk instead of using an in-memory cache.  The pre-image cache will likely get quite large, but that might not be a concern for an archive node, which already would have a large footprint on disk.